# Strange RealDigits rounding behavior with N

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

The last two digits of `N[Sqrt[85], 101]` are `49`, but the last term of `RealDigits[N[Sqrt[85], 101], 10, 100]` is `5`, where I expect it to be `4`. Changing `101` to `102` or larger number results in `4`, which is expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: Changing `101` to `102` changes the number you're computing the digits of....Different input, different output is certainly possible.  See Coolwater's answer for a reason why the first answer should end in a 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluating `Interval[N[Sqrt[85], 101]]` you will see that due to the uncertainty of floating point numbers, the exact number that is being approximated by `N[Sqrt[85], 101]` could just as well have `5` as its 100th digit.

Hence `RealDigits` is only well-defined up to and including the 99th digit. In upcoming versions the 100th digit may change between 4 or 5.

Comment: Another spin on it: What the OP's `RealDigits[..]` command is computing is not the digits of `Sqrt[85]`, but the digits of a number near it. And that number is closer to the 100-digit result ending in a 5 than the one ending in a 4.

Answer (score 2):

*Some remarks, not a complete answer:*

```
Trace[RealDigits[N[Sqrt[85], 101], 10, 100]]
```

Yields as last calculation:

```
RealDigits[9.2195444572928873100022742817627931572468050487224640080077522054426710
26801875460767894090793280564940339808878871684152124663346517172`101., 10, 100]
```

The value has more digits, so the rounding that `N[]` is producing in `'101` is somehow carried over in `RealDigits`.

A better way to run this would be to actually trim the precision before passing the calculation over to `RealDigits`.

```
RealDigits[SetPrecision[Sqrt[85], 101], 10, 100]
```

Yields the expected result.

Comment: Note that `SetPrecision[Sqrt[85], 101]` has a precision greater than `101`. It is equivalent to `N[Sqrt[85], 101 + Log10[2]]`, because `SetPrecision` sets the precision of the *numbers* in an expression (i.e. `85` becomes ``85`100``) and `y = Sqrt[x]` increases precision by one bit (dy/y = dx/2).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does it make sense for precision to not be an integer? I.e., will it actually potentially cause a different rounding?

Comment: Yes, I think it does make sense for two reasons. One is somewhat trivial: The computations are all done in binary and the precision is defined to be `-Log[10, dx/x]` which will be whatever number it is. The other is that it would cause a difference in rounding, in both output and internal computations.  For output, it's easy to demonstrate: ``1.59`2.`` vs. ``1.59`2.3``  For input, it's much harder to demonstrate. Arbitrary precision keeps a finite but unknown (to me) number of extra guard bits, so an internal rounding difference would be rare and normally confined to the guard bits.

Comment: An ill-conditioned example of an internal rounding difference: `SeedRandom[0]; data = (-1)^Range[10^6] RandomReal[{1, 101/100}, 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 10]; prec = 6; Print@InputForm@Total[N[data, prec]]; Print@InputForm@Total[N[data, prec + 0.3]]`...But maybe I didn't understand you. The principal use of precision is not to control rounding but to keep track of bounds on rounding error in a computation.

Comment: No, it's clear, thanks for the explanation.